# Aurelia - composing views dynamically

Tags: aurelia

I have a common container component into which I would like to display different components depending on what the user has selected. I have got this working using the  element in the container view and binding the view.model attribute to a model property, like this:

```
  <compose view-model="./${componentName}" if.bind="haveComponent" model.bind="stuff"></compose>
```

I have methods in the view model which change the value of {componentName} and different views are displayed.It does seem to work but something doesn't feel right, I'm not quite sure.

Is this a legitimate way to achieve this? I'm pretty new to Aurelia so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether StackOverflow is the right place to ask this question, maybe you'd be better off asking on the Aurelia github page. StackOverflow is better suited for answering more specific programming issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is legitimate use case for compose

Don't be shy and join [aurelia's discourse](https://discourse.aurelia.io/)